# click/change event for formio component

Tags: events, formio

I am using formio npm package to integrate the formbuilder in react application. I want to get change event for a select box. Is there any way I can configure or identify the change event triggered specific to a component(like a selectbox). I get change event for the entire form though.

Answer (score 0):

if (event.changed && event.changed.component.key === 'customerNumber' && event.changed.value)

Comment: This doesn't address the issue though.  The event listner is still on Change . There is a componentChanged event which can be used in formio

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "componentChanged" event in formio refer [the document here](https://help.form.io/developers/form-renderer#form-events) for more detailed event list and objects. You can listen to that event and add your actions in logic tab or Js side when you have any update like value change in that particular component.

Comment: Could you please explain to me why some of the events does not fire at all (except _'change' & 'submit'_)? All I do in my code is the following: `Formio.createForm(document.getElementById('formio'), components, _module.formOptions).then(function(form) { form.on('formLoad', function() { console.log('formLoad'); }); }`